# faces-redirect=true not working while creating and rendering view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am currently working on a JSF 2.2 application. As per requirements, I have created custom view handler (using `ViewHandlerWrapper`) for my application. All the methods are just passing to default view handler except renderView which I am overriding as follows -

```
private viewHandler viewHandlerWrapped = null;

renderView(FacesContext facesContext, UIViewRoot viewToRender) {
      String viewId = viewToRender.getViewId();
      if (viewId == some condition) {
          /* Do calculation to derive viewId */
      }
      UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandlerWrapped.createView(facesContext,viewId+"?faces-redirect=true");
      facesContext.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
      //now let system render the view
      viewHandlerWrapped.renderView(facesContext,viewRoot);
    }
```

The above is working fine and rendering & navigation is happening as expected. The only issue is `faces-redirect=true` is not working. The URL seems to be always one behind.

I have gone through many answers given in stackoverflow or internet. But nowhere I am able to find how to solve this.

I think I am doing something wrong e.g. `?faces-redirect=true` might not be the correct way while creating view. But I am not sure what can be done to correct this.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Can someone please help me with this? I am still not able to resolve it.

Comment: @BalusC.. Apologies for tagging you in! Can you please comment what may be incorrect here? I am trying from last two weeks but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for more than 4 weeks, I finally found a way to get the correct URL (instead of previous one). I am updating my answer here in case any one else falls into same problem -

"It looks like we can not use the `faces-redirect=true` the way I was using while creating and rendering the pages. It should be suffixed with form action. So I have changed my code as follows -

1) actions are returned on click of a button e.g.

```
public string doAction {
----
return "action?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

2) Code is updated to use implicit navigation wherever possible. With this, I didn't need to build my custom viewhandler as navigation is happening implicitly. So, I have scrapped the viewhandler.

With above two simple steps, the correct URL is being displayed on the browser now.